# Defined assembly is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, assemblies

I'm trying to figure out this exception error I'm getting in my script:

> Error  2   The type
>   'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=2010.2.11.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    C:\Users\user1\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\NAudio\Program.cs    27  13  Application

I'm using Net Framework 4.5
System.ComponentModel.Composition is listed in the References 
I tried removing the Assembly, cleaning the Project file and adding it again, but I still get this same error.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add more information about the type of application.  Perhaps posting the contents of csproj might help

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For an out of the box way to track down assembly binding problems use the fusion log...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

As a wild guess I'd say it could be a mix up of different versions of .NET

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you might be missing some dependency that System.ComponentModel.Composition relies on.  Try this out and see if it can point you to the missing dependency:

http://www.amberfish.net/